# Can i remove values-af , -am ... etc folders from the appcompat_v7?

Tags: android, android-appcompat

i am not using any menu or actionbar in my app and also i think these folders are for supporting different languages. So can i remove these extra files to reduce my .apk size?

Comment: You can, but it won't make a difference worth bothering over

Comment: i did it with google-play-service and it reduced approx 300Kb of my apk size. But since appcompat is for compatibility i am doubtful.

Comment: oh thanks alot :) ...and would it affect the app over different devices if i remove the same files from google-play-service?

Comment: It'd remove localisation etc.

Comment: well be careful while you remove once I wasted 3 hours because I removed about 50 kb worth images from a library and ended up messing my whole dev machine and workspace